# Margin bottom headerview in listview

Tags: android, listview, header

I'm implementing a listview that looks like this :

[image]

So basicly I have a listview, with a headerview. My problem is to set the space between the headerview and the rest of the listview. If anyone has a clue, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To set a gap below the header view you can just add marginBottom to the header view. That should do it. But like Pauland said, never ever EVER put a listview inside a scrollview. You are basically placing two vertical-scrolling views ontop of each other and Android can't tell which one to scroll when the user swipes!